# how to keep python time.sleep() function running after locking MacBook

Tags: python, macos

I am running a python script on my MacBook with a time.sleep() function in the script.
When I close my MacBook, the time.sleep() function stopped and resumed after logging in again. I am sure that the OS didn't enter sleep mode.
How can I keep the time.sleep() function running when the screen is locked?

Comment: How sure are you that it didn't go to sleep?

Comment: what do you mean by "close my MacBook".  if you mean closing the lid, then this will normally result in all CPU activity being suspended.  e.g. run `while date; do sleep 1; done` (in a bourne shell) and you'll probably see it stopping while the lid is closed.